# If $m,n,p$ and $m',n',p'$ produce the same Pythagorean triple, does the following have to hold? $m=m'$, $n=n'$ and $p=p'$.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, pythagorean-triples, primitive-roots

A Pythagorean triple is given by $(x,y,z)=(p(m^2-n^2),p(2mn),p(m^2+n^2))$.
Is there a way to show that $m=m'$, $n=n'$ and $p=p'$ or that there's possibly a counterexample where this isn't the case?

Comment: if both $(m,n)$ pairs follow the rules for primitive triples, namely they are coprime and not both odd, then yes. Otherwise, take $(m,n)$ such a pair, make that $p=4,$ let $m'=2m, n'=2n$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not Always valid :  take for example any $p,m,n$ with $ p\bmod 4\equiv 0$ and then take $p' = p/4\:,m' = 2m\:, n' = 2n$